# Why do I hear water running through my water heater until the breaker is turned off?

Tags: water, circuit-breaker, leak, pipe, heater

I heard water running, so I turned off the main water line outside, but the sound was still apparent. It was coming from the electric water heater and didn't stop until I flipped the breaker to the water heater.

We have hot water--really hot. Is it safe to leave it like that and is it a broken pipe under the house or a bad water heater? Thank you all for info.

Comment: We're going to need more information to help. The electrics in a water heater do not control water flow. Are you sure you're hearing water flowing and not the sounds of heating? Some water heaters, especially older ones, make hissing sounds.

Comment: If the shut off valve works, you should only get water out of the taps for a few seconds afterwards.  Turn off the breaker for the heater, if water gets low in the tank then the elements will burn out.

Comment: There's a perfectly obvious reason that water running sounds would continue until the breaker was shut off...

Comment: Could your water heater and house plumbing have a fast-hot-water pump and system that runs hot water to the taps all the time so you get hot water fast at the sinks instead of having to wait for the cool water to run out of the hot water pipes?

Comment: "fast-hot-water pump" often referred to as a recirculation pump. ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Bad water heater!

Seems likely that the **temperature/pressure relief valve** to release excessively hot or over-pressure water from the water heater had actuated, since you mention that the water is *really* hot, and the "running water sound" is coming from the water heater.

That may be plumbed outside, or to an exposed drain if done to code (the pipe  is not supposed to go to a concealed drain, it's supposed to be air-gapped and visible, since it indicates a problem that needs to be solved with the water heater, such as a welded thermostat contact that won't shut off.) You'd continue to have "running water sounds" if the heater was boiling, even with the water shut off. When you shut off the power, the boiling would stop, and so would the flow out the relief valve drain.

The valve is there to protect you from having an exploding water heater, which is a very bad thing. There's [a mythbusters episode where they disable it](https://youtu.be/rGWmONHipVo?si=LZfwPip0XrVyZVXn) and show the resulting explosion.

Leave the breaker to the water heater off, and turn the water back on. *Many* temperature/pressure relief valves seal poorly once they have been actuated, so you may still have a small leak through it. If so, you can look for where that pipe goes and see if it's dripping or flowing. If it's a leak elsewhere you'll hear it, undiminished. Even if it fully seals, you should see evidence of water having flowed out the relief valve pipe when you find the end of it.